# Ajust pictures in table to have them in the same height as text

Tags: html, css, image

I try to align my Images inside of an `td` tag to have the same height/layout as my Text?
thank u

My code so far:

```html
<table style="border-bottom: 0px solid #ddd; margin-top: 20px;">
  <tr>
    <td id="instagram">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/640/PNG/512/instagram-social-media-camera-photo_icon-icons.com_59107.png" alt="Instagram" width="15%" /></a> Instagram</td>
    <td id="facebook">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/640/PNG/512/facebook-letter-social-media-f_icon-icons.com_59105.png" alt="Facebook" width="15%" /></a> Facebook</td>
    <td id="twitter">
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/640/PNG/512/twitter-bird-animal-social-media_icon-icons.com_59106.png" alt="Twitter" width="15%" /></a> Twitter</td>
    <td id="youtube">
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/640/PNG/512/youtube-video-social-media-play_icon-icons.com_59108.png" alt="Youtube" width="15%" /></a> Youtube</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="tinytext" colspan="4"> Follow for more </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want images to be same height as text you can use `height: 1em`. *em* is relative to the **font-size of the element**. Which is in this situation 16px (font-size is 16px, image height is 16px).

It might differs because problem is that **your images has some blank/transparent space around them** - so it doesn't look like they are same height. Another problem might be font. Fonts has different line bases and it might also look like it is not the same height. So you might need to adjust your image height to make it more *look a like* same height instead of having it in same height (for example `height: 1.25em`, add some `margin` or maybe `vertical-align` in table or use `flex` etc.)

```css
img {
   height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="instagram">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/640/PNG/512/instagram-social-media-camera-photo_icon-icons.com_59107.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
            Instagram
        </td>
        <td id="facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/640/PNG/512/facebook-letter-social-media-f_icon-icons.com_59105.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
            Facebook
        </td>
        <td id="twitter">
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/640/PNG/512/twitter-bird-animal-social-media_icon-icons.com_59106.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
            Twitter
        </td>
        <td id="youtube">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com"><img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/640/PNG/512/youtube-video-social-media-play_icon-icons.com_59108.png" alt="Youtube"></a>
            Youtube
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

Example with pixel perfect image:

```css
img {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
This is my text <img src="https://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" />
```

---

Example which feels more like same height (used flex to center it in vertical direction):

```css
div {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
img {
   height: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div>
   UPPERCASE TEXT <img src="https://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" />
</div>
```